# How to search a string for a specific value then if found return value within that string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains a varchar column e.g.

```
Reference  Value      Comment 
GLJ:04302    23883.2  'Jnl: 1535 Job:A10738   S/o:'                                 
1088         8728.8   'Jnl: 3433 Wh:** Receipt        Stk:UPS Traing 7'             
1087         5700     'Jnl: 3433 Wh:** Receipt        Stk:Services'                 
1088         8728.8   'Jnl: 3433 Wh:** Receipt        Stk:UPS TRAINING U8'          
GLJ:04547    3700     'Jnl: 1635 Job:A7802    S/o:'                                
GLJ:04616    3610.7   'Jnl: 1656 Job:A11540   S/o:'                                 
GLJ:04624    3235.02  'Jnl: 1657 Job:A11691   S/o:'
```

Now i would like to search this comment string and if it finds the value `Job:` withing that string I want to return the value directly after the `:` and return from that position 8 chars so it will return e.g. 'A10738   '

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your strings containing "Job:" have that in the same position (ie starting at character 10), then this should work:

```
SELECT
  comment,
  RTRIM(SUBSTRING ( comment, 14, 8 )) as JobNumber

FROM
  table

WHERE
  comment LIKE '%Job:%'
```

But if the "Job:" item can start anywhere, you'll need something more robust:

```
SELECT
  comment,
  RTRIM(SUBSTRING ( comment, CHARINDEX ( "Job:" ,comment) + 4, 8 )) as JobNumber

FROM
  table

WHERE
  comment LIKE '%Job:%'
```

Another option (that is overkill for your scenario, but mentioning it here for prosperity) would be to use a RegEx.  RegEx is not native to SQL, but can be implemented in .NET via the CLR.  Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx#S3

**EDIT:** Note that I've included an `RTRIM()` in there to strip your trailing spaces from the job number (in case it's less than 8 characters). If you *need* the full 8, remove the `RTRIM()` from around the `SUBSTRING()`.

Comment: @user1546143 My pleasure, thanks for taking the time to accept. Also note added a comment about the RTRIM function that will give you less than 8 chars if the job number is less than 8 chars.